# Uploading and displaying image to mysql using html and php

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, base64

I'm trying to upload an image of my HTML form into my MySQL blob column. the insertion is done successfully but the display of the image does not work properly knowing that images inserted directly into MySQL are displayed correctly.

HTML code:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method='POST' action="add_question_submit.php" id="addQuestionForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
              <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="question" form="addQuestionForm" placeholder="Enter Question in brief.... " required></textarea><br>
              <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" required><br>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer" placeholder="Enter Correct Answer" name="answer"  required><br>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="category_id" placeholder="Enter category id (only numeric)" name="category_id" required><br>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="level_id" placeholder="Enter level id (only numeric)" name="level_id" required><br>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          </div>
        </form>
```

PHP code:

```
$file_temp = base64_encode( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) ); 
$image = getimagesize($file_temp);
$query = "INSERT INTO  questions(question_name, image, answer, category_id,level_id)VALUES('$question', '$image','$answer', '$category_id', '$level_id')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
header("Location: display_question.php");
```

display_question.php :

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" />'; ?></br><br/></td>
```

[image]

Comment: Storing image in table is bad idea

Comment: @SureshKamrushi,you have a better idea?

Comment: Aren't you storing the results of `getimagesize()` rather than the image?

Comment: I already tried with the storage of the variable $ file_temp but nothing happens.Always the insertion is complete and the display does not work.

Comment: As @Suresh Kamrushi says it's better to store images in directories on the file system and store references to the images in the database.

Comment: I am a beginner in php.Please can you help me with a complete example?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: If you actually store the image as a base64_encoded string.... You dont need to encode it again when you try and place it in an image tag

Comment: That is if you actually store `$file_temp` into column `image` and not the file size

Answer (score 0):

First you are storing the wrong information onto the database, you are storing the file size and not the encoded image.

```
$file_temp = base64_encode( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) ); 
$image_size = getimagesize($file_temp);
$query = "INSERT INTO  questions(question_name, image, answer, category_id,level_id)
                        VALUES('$question', '$file_temp','$answer', '$category_id', '$level_id')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
header("Location: display_question.php");
```

Second, if you have stored the base64 encoded version of the file onto the database you do not need encode it again when you retrieve it from the database so your `<img>` tag should be

```
<?php echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,$row[image]'/>"?>
</br><br/></td>
```

And thirdly **and most importantly** you need to be using parameterise bound queries to protect your app from [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
$file_temp = base64_encode( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) ); 
$image_size = getimagesize($file_temp);
$query = "INSERT INTO  questions
                      (question_name, image, answer, category_id,level_id)
                VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_params('sssss',  $question, 
                            $file_temp,
                            $answer,
                            $category_id,
                            $level_id);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if (!$result) {
    echo $conn->error;
}
header("Location: display_question.php");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but i have this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in ... "

Comment: sorry, missed a couple of commas. try again

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function which will upload the images to specific folder.
You can all below function like:

```
Param 1: is the folder where we need to store the new image  
Param 2: is FILES  
Param 3: if any prefix for the image we need to pass it.  
Param 4: if there is any previously uploaded image for same record. It should be deleted from the folder. Generally it is usefull when you are editing particluar record.  

uploadfile("profile",$_FILES,"profile_pic");
```

**Code is here:**

```
 function uploadfile($folder,$data,$preFix = "logo_",$previousImage="") {
        $location = (pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
        $uploads_dir = $location['dirname'] . "/assets/uploads/" . $folder . "/";
        $fileNames = "";
        $tmp_name = $data["tmp_name"];
        $name = $data["name"];
        $fileExtension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newfilename = $preFix . date("ymdhms") . '.' . $fileExtension;
        $fulldest = $uploads_dir . $newfilename;
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fulldest)) {
            if($previousImage != "")
                $this->removePreviousImage($folder, $previousImage);     //deleting existing image
            return $newfilename;
        } else {
            exit("Error File Uploading");
        }
    }
```